# Gitlab - What does "roles@[hash]" in a project means?

Tags: gitlab, hash

What does `roles @ hash` in a gitlab project means?

[image: roles @ hash]

When clicking on roles it forwards to a role folder. When clicking on the hash it forwards to a branch which name is just the hash.

[image: Just the hash]

The branch doesn't show up in branch list (only accessible by clicking on the hash) and is not editable.
The runner executes that "hash-branch" instead of master.

How is it possible to either edit that weird branch or change the executed branch to master?

thanks a lot!

Edit:

The runner stopped executing the job succesfully so i wanted to update a few things in the project. However, when changing these things (which causes the error) it looks like the runner still executes a old version of the project. I guess it's executing that hash branch, maybe because of the "roles@hash" thing. But it's not possible to delete or change that file or what ever it is.

Comment: A little context might be helpful. Obviously it's a folder at a specific location in your repository.

Comment: I don't have a GitLab handy to check it, but it could be a reference to a submodule.

Answer (score 0):

It's another repository that has been added to the repository you are browsing as a [Git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

The hash is not a branch, it's the hash of the revision of the target repository that has been committed to the main repository.

To check out the repository including submodules you need to specify the argument `--recurse-submodules`:

```
git checkout main --recurse-submodules
```

If the target repository has changed and you need to update it in your main repository you can just enter the directory and pull a newer version as you would with a regular git repo. Then you can commit it at the parent directory.

An example:

```
gerald@host:~/tmp/test$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
gerald@host:~/tmp/test$ cd test2
gerald@host:~/tmp/test/test2$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 287 bytes | 287.00 KiB/s, done.
From git.example.com:gerald/test2
   e4c940e..344b92d  main       -> origin/main
Updating e4c940e..344b92d
Fast-forward
 README.md | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
gerald@host:~/tmp/test/test2$ cd ..
gerald@host:~/tmp/test$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   test2 (new commits)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
gerald@host:~/tmp/test$ git commit -a -m "updated submodule test2 to current version"
[main 3d1857e] updated submodule test2 to current version
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, all makes more sense now. However there's nothing to merge in the roles repository. Is it possible to just delete the roles@hash file since it is referring to an old version of the repository? As i understood it this reference comes from the .submodules file, right ? (referring to master branch of roles repository).

Comment: It's a code repository. Make the changes you want, check if everything works, commit or restore it. We can't tell you what is reasonable for your repository because we don't know what's stored in it.